# mobex, @inject only specific part of store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

At present I am using mobx `<Provider store={store} />` where store includes all mobx store classes that have observables.

Inside of components I access it using

```
@inject("store")
@observe
class MyComponent ....
```

But this means that if I want to access just notification store I have to `this.props.store.notification.message` it for example and this becomes very verbose. Is there a way to get just the notification store? As we are injecting a string `"store"` instead of object I don't see a way to distructure it.

Comment: @EvgenySorokin that's actually a really good call, in this case though, how do I inject several of these stores into one component, is it possible to use several `@inject` decorators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decided to post it as the answer since it might help someone else:

As shown in the documentation of mobx-react (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react) Provider can accept any property that you pass to it, not only "stores".

So, the solution is to create an object with stores and pass it to Provider with spread operator (or any other way that is comfortable to you).

```
const stores = { 
     storeOne,
     storeTwo,
}

return (
   <Provider {...stores}>
      <MyComponent />
    </Provider>
)
```

If you're using mobx-react package and want to inject multiple stores - just pass stores to @inject function separated by comma

```
@inject('storeOne', 'storeTwo')
```

I created a pen with an example of multiple stores injection: https://codepen.io/evgen/pen/NgpVMw